# Monitor(Log) different threads' execution

Tags: java

I am writing java program that creates different instances of Runnable objects given by someone and then runs them. For instance user gives me a .class file with runnable class and I create instance of that object and run it. Everything works fine until I decided to monitor every different thread's progress. Lets say that current Runnable object print all the numbers from 1 to 9 in console. I want to catch that output and return it as a String. Using `System.setOut(..)` prevents me from using console, so it is not an option.

Answer (score 3):

Using `setOut` doesn't prevent you from using the console, if you save it first and it is your only option unless you use byte code instrumentation.

```
static final PrintStream OUT = System.out;
static {
   // capture all System.out
   System.setOut(new MyPrintStream());

   OUT.println("Print as normal");
}

class MyPrintStream extends PrintStream {
    final ThreadLocal<StringBuilder> text = ThreadLocal.withInitial(() _> new StringBuilder());

    public void print(String s) {
       StringBuilder sb = text.get();
       sb.append(s);
    }

    public void println(String s) {
       StringBuilder sb = text.get();
       sb.append(s).append('\n');
       // do something with sb.
    }
```

Comment: Aw, that's pretty neat solution to my problem, I had not think of. Thank you :)

Comment: @miroslavlalev I have added how you can use a ThreadLocal to collect the output of each thread.

Comment: I tried to upvote you before I write my comment but I need 15 reputation :(